# Data sampling based on the value of a variable in R

Tags: r, random

It might be easy, but I'm not able to find a way to sample based on a variable in a database. Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(24), nrow=12))
df$color <-  factor(rep(c("blue", "red", "yellow", "pink"), each=3))
```

which gives:

```
         X1     X2  color
 1  -0.1835 -0.664   blue
 2  -1.2774 -0.564   blue
 3   1.6395  0.952   blue
 4  -0.3831  0.136    red
 5   1.2142  0.652    red
 6   0.5675  1.435    red
 7  -0.0565  0.364 yellow
 8  -1.8347  2.511 yellow
 9  -0.6089  0.470 yellow
 10 -1.0594  1.344   pink
 11 -0.1610 -0.540   pink
 12 -1.0791 -0.706   pink
```

I want to random select a subset of colors, and create a new data.frame including all observation having the selected colors. A possible solution is the following (where I select two colors)

```
df[df$color %in% sample(levels(df$color),2),]
```

and get:

```
        X1     X2 color
 4  -0.383  0.136   red
 5   1.214  0.652   red
 6   0.567  1.435   red
 10 -1.059  1.344  pink
 11 -0.161 -0.540  pink
 12 -1.079 -0.706  pink
```

but I'm looking for alternative methods (to be used in very large databases)

Comment: How big should the subset of colours be? And what is wrong with your solution?

Comment: First of all I don't want to restrict to factor variables. Second, I'm not sure this is very efficient when we have large databases.

Comment: I think it would be as efficient as most options. If you have different types of things to sample from, you could create a variable using `unique()` on a given column, and it would create a list to sample from to plug into your subset expression and it would accept any type of object, integers, characters, factors, numerical...i